# Android - I want to use the same XML layout for multiple buttons in my app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a little confused as to what I should be doing.  I've read about fragments and I'm not sure if I should be using them here.  I have 3 button in my main_layout file.  What I'm doing incorrectly (I know) is that I have 3 different (but really similar) result xml files and 3 activity.java files.  The result page is the same, just different text.  There's no reason to have so many java files etc.  I know there has to be a better way?

In my main_layout.xml, I have 3 ImageButtons:

[image]

In my MainActivity.java:

```
ImageButton ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ib1.setOnClickListener(this);

ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ib2.setOnClickListener(this);

ImageButton ib3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
ib3.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton1) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, OneInfo.class));
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton2) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, TwoInfo.class));
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton3) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, ThreeInfo.class));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map all 3 buttons to a single activity.  Add an integer extra "mode" to it which specifies which of the 3 modes to use.  In the activity, check the mode and set the text of the views that differ to the appropriate string using setText.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you further explain what you mean by the extra "mode"?

Comment: An Intent can have "extras".  Its basically a set of parameters in key-value form.

Answer (score 2):

To cut down on the repetitive code, you can use a tag on the buttons:

```
int[] btnIds = { R.id.imageButton1, R.id.imageButton2, R.id.imageButton3 };
Class<?> classes = { OneInfo.class, TwoInfo.class, ThreeInfo.class };
for (int i = 0; i < btnIds.length; ++i) {
    View btn = findViewById(btnIds[i]);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn.setTag(classes[i]);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Class<?> tag = (Class<?>) v.getTag();
    if (tag != null) { // just in case
        startActivity(new Intent(this, tag));
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense.  Is is possible to eliminate the extra classes and layouts and just setText for each?

Comment: @user1040259 - That should be doable in exactly the same way. You probably should use an array of text resource IDs to do it. It would then just be an extra line or two in the first loop (to retrieve the text view and set the text for each index i).